# Scrolling a very large GtkDrawingArea

Tags: c++, c, gtk, gtk2

I have a `GtkDrawingArea` that is used to visualize data.
Depending on the database and user input the drawing can grow really large (larger than the maximum allowed `GtkDrawingArea` size). Therefore I would like to use a drawing area that is just as big as the current window and update it manually upon scrolling.

If I use the ScrolledWindow + Viewport method to add scroll-bars to the drawing area it does obviously not work because the drawing area is not big enough to need scroll-bars.

Is there any way that that I can trick the viewport into thinking that the underlying widget is larger than it actually is? 
If not what would be the best way to solve this problem?

Note: I am using Gtk2 and switching to Gtk3 is not a possibility.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to subclass `GtkDrawingArea` and override the `set_scroll_adjustments` signal. [GtkWidget docs](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk2/stable/GtkWidget.html)

In this signal you will get the adjustments for the scrolled window. I wrote some code a few years back that you can look at to see how to implement it.

[MarlinSampleView code](https://gitlab.gnome.org/Archive/marlin/blob/master/marlin/marlin-sample-view.c#L2984)

This code was able to pretend that the widget was millions of pixels wide when in reality it wasn't any bigger than the window.

Answer (score 0):

It turned out to be quite simple:

The `GtkScrolledWindow` has another constructor which can be used to set the `GtkAdjustments` that the scrolled window should use.

```
//These adjustments will be attached to the scrollbars.
prvt->hAdjustment = GTK_ADJUSTMENT(gtk_adjustment_new(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0));
prvt->vAdjustment = GTK_ADJUSTMENT(gtk_adjustment_new(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0));

GtkWidget* scrolledTree = gtk_scrolled_window_new(prvt->hAdjustment, prvt->vAdjustment);
gtk_scrolled_window_add_with_viewport(GTK_SCROLLED_WINDOW(scrolledTree), drawing_area);
```

Now, whenever the size of the drawing changes you just need to modify the `GTKAdjustments` to simulate the change. There is no need to actually resize the drawing area.

```
gtk_adjustment_set_lower(prvt->hAdjustment, 0);
gtk_adjustment_set_step_increment(prvt->hAdjustment, 1);
gtk_adjustment_set_page_increment(prvt->hAdjustment, 10);
gtk_adjustment_set_upper(prvt->hAdjustment, picture_width);
gtk_adjustment_set_page_size(prvt->hAdjustment, scrollArea_width);
gtk_adjustment_changed(prvt->hAdjustment);
```

Notice that I call `gtk_adjustment_changed` in the end. This is important, otherwise the `ScrolledWindow` will not update the scrollbars.

Finaly the `value_changed` callback of the `GtkAdjustmens` can be used to catch the scroll events and adjust the drawing.

Edit: This does not work properly because the `GtkScrolledWindow` receives the scroll event
as well and moves the image :(